# Prepopulate form with current_user name - Rails 4 + the_Comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to prepopulate the comment form with the user that is currently logged in (through Devise + Twitter omniauth). But I got not idea how could I indice :title to be pre-populated with 'current_user name'.

```
    = form_for Comment.new, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f|
      .error_notifier{ style: "display:none" }
      %label= t('the_comments.form.title')

      %p= f.text_field :title

      %label= t('the_comments.form.contacts')
      %p= f.text_field :contacts

      %label= t('the_comments.form.content')
      %p= f.text_area :raw_content

      %p.trap
        - TheComments.config.empty_inputs.each do |name|
          = text_field_tag name, nil, autocomplete: :off, tabindex: -1, id: nil

      = hidden_field_tag :tolerance_time, 0, id: nil, class: :tolerance_time

      = f.hidden_field :commentable_type, value: commentable.class
      = f.hidden_field :commentable_id,   value: commentable.id
      = f.hidden_field :parent_id, class: :parent_id

      %p
        = f.submit t('the_comments.form.create'), class: :btn
        = t('the_comments.form.thank_you')
```

I'm using [the_Comments](https://github.com/the-teacher/the_comments) as a gem for commenting.

Solved with the comments: value: current_user.name

Comment: You can try below code

    <%= f.text_field :title,value: current_user.name  %>

Comment: Indeed. That's simple tweak worked.

Comment: @NidhiSarvaiya can you add that as an answer so this question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code

```
<%= f.text_field :title,value: current_user.name %>
```